# Resetting a microcontroller with a button connected to Vcc

Tags: power, reset, debounce

I would like to have a way to reset my PIC by removing power from the chip.  My hacker self thinks that the simplest way would be to add a resistor between the output of my LDO and Vcc on the PIC, and then add a button between GND and after the resistor.  To avoid any potential issues with switch bounce, I figure I could add a cap in parallel with the button and a resistor in between, like this: (ignore component values, those are the defaults from the editor)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6ApfL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is there anything seriously wrong with doing it like this?  I'm trying to keep it simple and not require a bunch of components.

Comment: Resetting a μC with a pushbutton is usually done by pulling down the reset pin (/MCLR on a PIC). Is there a reason why this cannot be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll suffer variable voltage drop depending on load current. It doesn't look too elegant.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc9Q9b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Power cut button.*

How about using a normally closed pushbutton? Switch bounce isn't a problem. The circuit will just reset again.

Comment: So basically, even my original idea (before what I had posted), which was what you had outlined, but without the capacitor, would have been a better solution?  :)  Thank you for your input / insight!

Comment: Now the trick is finding a NC surface mount button...

Comment: [Push Button Switch, IP57, SPDT-NO/NC, Surface Mount, On-(On)](http://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/push-button-switches/7931582/). [Black Cap Tactile Switch, SPDT 30 mA 2mm](http://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/tactile-switches/7347362/).

Comment: thanks for the link, wow that thing is monstrous!  I wonder why no one makes those tiny SMD buttons NC?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have an /MCLR pin?

You didn't write which PIC you are using so I'm just cutting and pasting this from a PIC16(L)F1717/8/9 datasheet:

> 5.5       MCLR
>
> The MCLR is an optional external input that can reset the device. The MCLR
>   function is controlled by the MCLRE bit of Configuration Words and the LVP bit of
>   Configuration Words (Table 5-2).
>
> 5.5.1         MCLR ENABLED
>
> When MCLR is enabled and the pin is held low, the device is held in Reset. The MCLR pin is connected to VDD through an internal weak pull-up. The device has a noise filter in the MCLR Reset path. The filter will detect and ignore small pulses

Comment: Sorry, no MCLR, this is actually a PICAXE.

Comment: Aha, bummer... It is a good idea to mention the exact IC in your question. PICAXE-40X2 for instance has a reset pin.